# How to handle multiple listener in java script

Tags: javascript, html, sencha-touch, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.1

I am try to implement handling multiple touch listener and key listener  in java script .Can anybody tell how to handle?

I have tried this way it is not working

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchstart','touchend','keypress' function(e){
```

Thanks

Comment: @4dgaurav that is not what OP is asking....

Comment: `function addEvents(el, events, fn) {
        events.forEach(function(e) {
            el.addEventListener(e, fn, false);
        });
    }` and call this as `addEvents(document.getElementById('id'), ['click', 'keyup', 'touchend'], handler);`